# Linkedin Full Profile API access for a Course Project

Tags: linkedin-api

My team and I  are undertaking a course on Ar/Vr, and we are trying to access profile information from Linkedin. I need access to full profile information (r_fullprofile), as the (r_basicprofile) is not sufficient for the project.

I understand that access to these API's are only through [Partner Programs](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs), but since I am a student, I cannot find the valid program that I should apply to.

How to proceed with the above situation, or any kind of access that I can request for the project?

Comment: you should contact linkedin ...

Comment: what is your question? SO is not support of other companies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for LinkedIn support, not StackOverflow

Answer (score -1):

i would consider using r_basic anyway. requesting such a partnership will take up to more then a month of waiting.

also you should look at the possiblities of the linkedin people V1 api.

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(firstName,lastName,headline,positions:(company,title,summary,startDate,endDate,isCurrent),industry,location:(name,country:(code)),pictureUrl,publicProfileUrl,emailAddress)?format=json
```

this are some things you can get from the basic, i probably missed alot because i do not need them. do you need something specifc ?